# How to control popover-arrow position in bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use popover in bootstrap 4.The toggle button I set in on the top right corner.

first if I set the popover on the buttom:

```
    $(function () {
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
placement: 'bottom'
})
```

the popover will be displayed with part off the screen like:

[image]

then I try to use 'auto' instead of 'bottom' in the placement, but in this case the popover does not work...

after that I use 'bottom' in the placement again and use offset to move popover 50px to the left and increase the width of the popover:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
placement: 'bottom',
offset: '0 50px'
})
```

css:

```
.popover-content{
width: 270px;
}
```

then the popover show like this:

[image]

now the popover-arrow position is misplaced, I try to move the arrow position with ''shown.bs.popover' event like:

```
 $('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
 $('.popover.bottom .popover-arrow:after').css('right', 50 + 'px');
});
```

but it doesn't work....

Does any one know how to move the arrow postion or hide the arrow when shows up?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adjust the position of the arrow with the following styles:

**Bootstrap 3**

```
.popover.bottom > .arrow {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

**Bootstrap 4**

```
.popover.bs-tether-element-attached-top::after,
.popover.bs-tether-element-attached-top::before{
    left: 65%;
}
```

Comment: I think it works for bootstrap 3, but I am using bootstrap 4

Comment: You're right, yin. I've updated my answer, see if it works.

Comment: @r-costa Sorry for jumping in late, but is it also possible to change the position of the arrows individually via a custom class or option?

Answer (score 1):

Users that might try React-Bootstrap v1 *that uses Bootstrap 4* for bootstrapping popover arrow you can adjust the position of the arrow with the following class targeting:

**React-Bootstrap v1.0.0-beta.5**

```
.popover .arrow::after,
.popover .arrow::before {
  left: 104px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrap 4 here is how I worked this out.

So in JQuery you listen for the `show.bs.popover` event, like this:

```
$('#element-id').on('show.bs.popover', function(){
});
```

then, inside that event you execute the css altering code for bootstraps `.popover` element:

```
$('.popover').css('left', '65%');
```

Does not work? Maybe it is because the altering code fires just before the element is created/shown in the page, so the css applies to a missing element. Try placing the css altering code in a timeout. The final code would look like this:

```
$('#element-id').on('show.bs.popover', function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.popover').css('left', '65%');
  }, 1);
});
```

My answer applies to specific popover. You can work it out from here I guess.

Another option is to add a CSS rule for the `.popover` element in your CSS file with `!important`, ex:

```
.popover { left: 65% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did like below.

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('show.bs.popover', function () {
setTimeout(function () {
    $('.popover.fade.show').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.hasClass('left-loaded')) {
            $this.addClass('left-loaded')
            var $left = parseInt($('.arrow', $this).css('left')) + parseInt(25) + "px"; 
           // change 25 as per your need
            $this.find('.arrow').css('left', $left);
        }
    })

}, 100);
});
```