# Bootstrap tooltip arrow customization / tooltip positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using [bootstrap tooltip](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/)  to display a tooltip with an image in it. I am so far this much successful

[image]

How ever my requirement looks like this

[image]

I need to move the arrow upward so it matches the design, Is there a way we can customize the position  of the arrow ?

The below function works on mouseoverevent

```
function showToolTip(elem) {
            var ttContent = '<img class=\'ttImage\'   src=\'http:\/\/getbootstrap.com\/apple-touch-icon.png\' \/>';
            $(elem).addClass("filter-text-highlight");
            if (!$(elem).parent('a.ttTooltip').length) {
                $(elem).wrap('<a data-toggle=\"tooltip\" class=\"ttTooltip\" style=\"text-decoration:none\" title=\"' + ttContent + ' \">');
                $('a[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
                    animated: 'fade',
                    placement: 'right',
                    html: true,
                });
                $(elem).tooltip().mouseover();
            }

        }
```

Comment: you can make your own tooltip. that will grant you more freedom like a div with opacity 0 and position absolute but relative to parent div not body. and on hover just change opacity to 1

Comment: if you are still using bootstrap 4 like in your tag try this: [How to control popover arrow position in bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41017943/how-to-control-popover-arrow-position-in-bootstrap-4)

Answer (score -1):

You can create your own tooltip that gives you more freedom. and it's pretty easy.
here is sample snippet. you just have to change opacity on hover a div.

```css
.parent{
  position:relative;
  display:inline;
}
.tooltip{
  opacity:0;
  position:absolute;
  right:-180px;
  top:0;
  background-color:#cccccc;
  height:40px;
  width:150px;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:5px;
}
.tooltip::before{
  content:"";
  width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
  position:absolute;
  left:-20px;
border-width: 10px 20px 10px 0;
border-color: transparent #cccccc transparent transparent;
}

.hover:hover + .tooltip{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button class="hover">Hover Me</button>
  <div class="tooltip">hello World</div>
</div>
```